# How can I disable IPython startup scripts when executing a notebook via Papermill?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, papermill

I have a Juypyter notebook that is executed by various users using Papermill. I want the outputs to be reproducible, independent of the user that is executing the notebook.  I have found that some users have [IPython startup scripts](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/config/overview.html#startup-files) and these scripts have been negatively impacting the reproducibility of the outputs.

How can I configure Papermill to not execute the IPython startup scripts?